# module has no exports in typescript lib

Tags: typescript

I define a simple function in typescript public lib `index.ts` like this:

```
export function demo(){
    return 1;
}
```

when I added the public lib in `package.json` and use the function in my project like this:

```
import{demo} from "wheel/dist/index";
demo();
```

show compile error:

```
export 'demo' (imported as 'demo') was not found in 'wheel/dist/index' (module has no exports)
 @ ./src/background/index.ts 2:0-111 9:8-23 12:8-32 15:8-19
```

why did this happen? what should I do to fix it? this is the public lib `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": { 
    /* Language and Environment */
    "target": "es2016",                                  /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */
    
    /* Modules */
    "module": "commonjs",                                /* Specify what module code is generated. */
    
    /* Emit */
    "declaration": true,                              /* Generate .d.ts files from TypeScript and JavaScript files in your project. */
    "outDir": "./dist", 
    "esModuleInterop": true,                             /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` for type compatibility. */
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,                         /* Disable resolving symlinks to their realpath. This correlates to the same flag in node. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,            /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */

    /* Type Checking */
    "strict": true,                                      /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "skipLibCheck": true                                 /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
  },
  "exclude": [
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

and this is my `package.json` of the public lib:

```
{
  "name": "js-wheel",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "build": "tsc",
    "watch:build": "tsc --watch",
    "watch:server": "nodemon './dist/index.js' --watch './dist'",
    "start": "npm-run-all clean build --parallel watch:build watch:server --print-label",
    "release": "tsc && npm publish"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/chrome": "^0.0.178",
    "dayjs": "^1.10.7",
    "npm": "^8.4.1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/js-wheel.git"
  },
  "author": "jiangtingqiang@gmail.com",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/js-wheel/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/js-wheel#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^27.4.7",
    "typescript": "^4.5.5"
  }
}
```

I have searching from internet and found many demo code just like what I write. I searching for hours still did not find any clue where is going wrong with my code. I import the public lib in current project like this:

```
"js-wheel":"jiangxiaoqiang/js-wheel"
```

Comment: what is in the `package.json` ??

Comment: I have pasted the package.json of the public lib.@NalinRanjan

Comment: Have you tried `import{demo} from "js-wheel";` instead of `import{demo} from "wheel/dist/index";`? How are you importing this public lib ?? I mean, can you share the `package.json` in which you have added this public lib as dependency?

Comment: Though even that should have worked.

Comment: I think you should share the json files of the project where you are importing this. Both `package.json` and `tsconfig.json`...

Answer (score 2):

I am facing a similiar problem recently, try to tweak the typescript compilerOptions config like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": { 
    /* Language and Environment */
    "target": "es5",                                  /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */
    
    /* Modules */
    "module": "esnext", 
}
```

this is the final code:

```
// public lib index.ts
export function demo(){
    return 1;
}

// current project import and invoke
import { demo } from "js-wheel/dist/index";

demo();
```